# Is there a way to extract Access Modules without opening the file?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I ended up corrupting my database to where every time I attempt to open it, I get error 3022, "changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index."

Recovery of the file does not seem possible and my previous back up is a month ago. I have been able to extract everything but the Modules, which is what I need to recover the most. None of the standard ways I have found work because they require the ability to open the database (For example, trying to set it as a VBA reference still give the same error.)

Is there any way to get the modules or code out of the file without opening it?

Edit:
Was finally able to get access to the file. Using DBEngine.CompactDatabase it was able to do a compact and repair. The issue has boiled down to the "MSysAccessStorage" table is corrupt, and says "Id is not an index in this table". I know have access to everything, except the modules, which I can't open without the MSysAccessStorage working.

I'm going to keep poking at it but I'm not sure what options I have for fixing a system table. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: If the import/export wizard will not work, then I expect not. Why is the db attempting to make changes to table when it opens? Does code run when opening? Have you tried opening with shift key bypass?

Comment: I have tried using the shift key with no luck. There is nothing set up to run when opening, and I even went so far as using a different database and DROPTABLE to remove all the tables and it is still happening.

Comment: Might find a third party to recover db at a price and then still no guarantee will succeed. File just might be corrupted beyond recovery. Google "Access database recovery solutions".

Comment: Perhaps when it does open and give the message, the particular table is on the screen.  Pressing ESC to undo the insertion of improper index may work.

Comment: Maybe `Application.SaveAsText acModule, ModuleName,Filename"`

Comment: Did you try `Alt + F11` key press to bring up VBA editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Visual Basic for Applications project has been corrupted. The original database doesn't even have any VBProjects when listing a count. I'm going to call this one a lost cause. Thanks everyone that tried to help.